Using Blender on ARM64 architecture
I was stoked when I saw the latest news from Qualcomm about native CPU support for blender with Snapdragon. I'm slightly confused though: does this mean I should get the current LTS build, or do I specifically need to choose the daily build which has the ARM64 version?
I tried the current LTS (4.2.3) but it doesn't seem optimised.

The release version is what you want, unless you want to try out new features in potentially buggy experimental versions. You don't mention in what way(s) the current release version doesn't seem optimized. That isn't a subject suited to this site. If you can explain as clearly as possible the specific problem(s) about optimization, you might get a response to that question on the Blender Artists forum: blenderartists.org/c/support/technical-support/49
